# Excel application close before finishing running a macro using COM pywin32

Tags: python, excel, com, pywin32, win32com

I have a simple process were i call multiple macro in a workbook using `win32com.client`

```
import win32com.client

xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True
xl.DisplayAlerts = False
xl.AskToUpdateLinks = False

# run macros
xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename="c:\test\example.xlsm", ReadOnly=1)
xl.Calculation = -4135
xl.Application.Run("example.xlsm!mod.macro1")
xl.Application.Run("example.xlsm!mod.macro2")
xl.Application.Quit()
```

for some reason, python doesnt wait for `Application.Run()` to finish before calling `xl.Application.Quit()`.

some notes:

1. the macro open and close multiple files
2. the `mod.macro1` in excel also has a `Application.OnTime(Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), "macro4")` call, which might be problematic

thx for your help

Comment: Are the macros attempting to update the file? (ReadOnly)

Comment: no, only updating other files which are open by the macro ( not in read only )